# Python login to website giving response 405 using requests.Session()

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a code to log in to a website but keep getting response 405. It's one of the first times I use python and have been researching for a while. The code should be able to log in and download a file.

Here's the code (email and password were replaced):

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    payload = {'userName': 'email', 'password': 'password'}
    retur = s.post("https://movielens.org/login", data=payload)
    wl = s.get('https://movielens.org/api/users/me/movielens-wishlist.csv', allow_redirects=True)
    open('movielens-wishlist.csv', 'wb').write(wl.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Response 405 means: Method not allowed.

HTTP has different methods like GET, POST, PUT, etc.

A webpage doesn’t provide all of them, a subset from these methods will be provided, some may provide GET, POST, PUT, others only provide GET.

It might be possible that **the webpage you are trying to access doesn’t provide POST or GET method**(depending on what line the error is coming from)

Your problem has nothing to do with python